# Matlab accessing the inner array of a 2d array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Matlab is really driving me crazy on this point. I just want to access the inner array of a 2d array.

E.g.:

```
A = [1,1; 2,2; 3,3]
B = [4,4; 5,5; 6,6]
C = [7,7; 8,8; 9,9]
D = [0,0; 1,2; 3,4]

E = [A,B,C,D]
```

how do I get e.g. `B` out of `E` again?

By this I mean in the exact same writing styl like `X = [4,4; 5,5; 6,6]`

Comment: I am no sure I understand the question. The syntax you use concatenates the array to a new one, it is not an array of arrays. 
If you want an array of array, even though that is ideal in MatLab, you could use a cell,  E = {A,B,C,D}. Then you can get B back using E{2}

Comment: @crown42 thats what I was looking for. thx :)

Comment: `X = E(:, 3:4)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you use concatenates the array to a new one, it is not an array of arrays. 
If you want an array of arrays, you could use a cell, E = {A,B,C,D}. Then you can get B back using E{2}.

Cells are general containers, each element can contain whatever you want, it does not have to be the same data type. See [What is a cell?](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html)

Answer (score 2):

You concatenated *A, B, C, D* horizontally into a new array *E*. That is not array of arrays, as the other answer pointed out. Suppose the new array is what you want. If you like to extract original *B* from *E*, you will need to know *A* and *B*'s size, in this case both are 3x2. So You can do following:

```
X = E(:, 3:4); % 3 is size(A,2)+1, numel(3:4) is size(B,2)
```

Also I think you did not really mean "writing style", since that is just a way to write assignment.